# Gmail + Firefox hang?

Tags: firefox, gmail, freeze

In the past couple of days I've been having trouble getting into gmail from firefox. In IE and chrome it works as usual but in Firefox it hangs in the "Loading" screen and never finishes.

I've tried F5 and Ctrl+F5 but both don't seem to change anything.

All other google application seem to work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: what operating system?  might be related...

Comment: Windows Vista aaaaaa

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Firebug installed, and enabled for the site?  That's known to slow gmail down.

Comment: nope. no Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply. Clear your cache.

Also try Firefox in safe mode (type 'firefox safe' in search).

And try https://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0 to disable any Gmail labs.

Go with Basic HTML version if worse comes to worse.

Comment: I did. nothing changed.

Comment: @shoosh: updated with more possible solutions